# Is it possible to script adding a PWA app to homescreen?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

To automate the set up of multiple Android devices, I'd like to be able to programmatically add a PWA app to the home screen. Of course, the app exists on the internet already, and the URL is known at script time. I just want to remove the manual steps of first navigating to the app via the Chrome browser, and adding to home screen.

I'm imagining that there may be some adb shell commands to add the 'app', or to launch Chrome with some arguments that'll add the app, or...? But my searches thus far haven't yielded a solution.

Thanks!!

Comment: The user needs to be on your HTTPS site in the browser and they need to explicitly agree to the install. It cannot be installed without their permission.

Comment: I can understand not being able to do it in the browser. But I own the device, and I'm connected as an admin to run arbitrary scripts. I was really hoping to have more options at my disposal! Thanks, Mathias.